# How do I change hard coded text in a h2 tag that is specified by a class?

Tags: javascript, class

I am working on a coding challenge for class. My issue is that I cant for the life of me figure out my problem right now. When my prompt pops up the player is suppose to enter a player name. After the player  enters in the player name the hard coded h2 tag that is specified by a class name pName is suppose to change to what the player has entered in the prompt window.  I can easily change them both to an Id and have it work that way but i want to follow the rules. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWWlf.png)

[image]

Comment: Post the code along with the question please.

Comment: Please post your code in a code block instead of an image

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

• `getElementById` - returns only one element, which has innerHTML and other properties.

• `getElementsBy...` returns a list of elements. The list doesn't have innerHTML. At first, you have to get the required element by index from that list, and then work with it.

• `getElementsByClassName` the returned list is **live**. Each time, when any of it's element is requested, it will recollect all elements from scratch. In most cases you don't really need that behavior.

• `querySelectorAll('.className')` collects all elements only once and returns a static list.

• `innerHTML` is used only if you are going to insert an actual HTML-string. In other cases, `textContent` is preferred.

```js
let test = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

test[0].textContent = "First element!";
test[1].textContent = "Second element!";

/***************/

let query = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

query[2].textContent = "Third element!";
query[3].textContent = "Fourth element!";
```

```css
.test { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; }
```

```html
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

Also, you can write a simple function, to change all contents at once:

```js
text('.test', "Changed text by class!");
text('#test-id', "Changed text by Id !!!");


function text(elems, text){  
  document.querySelectorAll(elems).forEach(function(elem){
    elem.textContent = text;
  });
}
```

```css
p { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; }
```

```html
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>

<p id="test-id">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `document.getElementsByClassName(name)`, which returns an array-like object containing all the elemets with that class. You should access the element you want in that object. You can get the first element with:

```js
elements[0]
// or
elements.item(0)
```

`getElementById` returns a a single HTMLElement, and not an array of them. Which is why it worked with id for you in this case.

Comment: My bad, it is similar to an array